# Web Service wsse security implementation

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-rpc

I am creating a web service using IBM JAX-RPC/JAX-WS. I am trying to implement the wsse security but not able to figure out the exact steps for achieving the same. I will be using RSA 7.5 and Websphere 7 for this web service.

Reading the documentation, I was totally lost since I am new to it and don't have any idea about the same.

Can someone list me the steps for how to implement the wsse security for the web service?

I have been struggling on this since past few days.

**EDIT**

I want the authentication to be done in the header, it should look something like this:

```
<header>
    <authenticationInfo>
        <userID></userID>
        <password></password>
    </authenticationInfo>
</header>
```

Other than using the handler and altering the header content, is there some other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Just curious, any compulsions for not using handler mechanism ?

Answer (score 1):

For web services (SOAP based), the security part is generally handled by [web services handlers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tipjax2/index.html). Handlers are applicable for both the client and server side. For typical security use case,

1. On [client side](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/), the [handlers intercept](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iicdoc/v1r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iic.doc/security/sec_webserv_example.html) the request before being send to server and **inserts a security header** in the SOAP message.
2. On server side, the handlers intercept the request and **check** for the SOAP request contains appropriate security headers. This happens before it handled by request handlers.

Here is a nice link on [WS security in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977327.aspx) I came across. Its not IBM or java specific but an informative read nevertheless.

To answer you question for step by step guide, I could not find any standard  RSA 7.5 specific articles but since JAX-RPC is standard specification, it should be same. Here is once such example ([Part1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0803_chung/0803_chung.html),[Part2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0804_chung/0804_chung.html))

Comment: In RPC, the handler is created using GeneralHandler whereas in WS, the handler is created using the SOAPHandler. I know how to implement them as well. Is it like other than using a handler there is no possible way to implement the security? I have edited the above post providing further inputs, please ignore RPC/WS while replying. I am comfortable with both.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere has built-in support for WS-Security. See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.webservice.wsfp.doc/topics/csecurews.html.